# Join data frames where 'by' is an expression to get column name

Tags: r, join, merge

I am writing a loop to join data frames in R and I am using the merge function. Here's the code I have:

```
for (j in 1:5){
  if(j == 1){
    iteration <- merge(iteration, paste0("var", j), 
                       by.x = eval(as.name(paste0("x", j))), 
                       by.y = "code", all.x = TRUE)
  }
}
```

Iteration is a data frame I have in the global environment and I have data frames titled var1, var2, var3 etc. I am trying to merge the iteration dataframe with each var data frame in the loop. Using the code I have now, I get ***Error in fix.by(by.y, y) : 'by' must specify a uniquely valid column***

I understand that by.x needs to be a column name specified the same way I have for by.y. However, I have variables x1, x2, x3 defined from previous functions in my global environment that correspond to the column names in datasets var1, var2, so I would like to use these names for the by.x part. Is there a way to call the names x1, x2 defined in my global environment for by.x in this loop? Or is there an alternative to merge that will allow me to do this better?

Comment: Column names in the iteration dataframe and var dataframes are not the same, hence I need to use by.x and by.y

Comment: I would try `Reduce(function(...) merge(..., mget(paste0("var", j)))`  Some reproducible example and expected output will be preferrred for testing the code.

Comment: `merge` **expects** character column names. I think your example will work if you just delete the `eval()` and `as.name()` in your `by.x`. It is the `y` data frame (second argument) that needs to be an object, so perhaps wrap `paste0("var", j)` in `get()`.

Comment: @Gregor Thanks the get worked. I didn't realize that the y data frame wasn't being recognized as an object because it was being captured through `paste0`. Using `eval` for the y data frame will also return the same thing as `get` so is one better than the other, or a preference?

Comment: `get` is safer. This is the job `get` is made for: you have a string, you want an object. `eval` is made for evaluating arbitrary R code.